# declare variable for a postgresql query using like and union

Tags: postgresql

I want to do this:

```
select * from table_1 where table_1.column1 ilike '%value%' union
select * from table_1 where table_1.column2 ilike '%value%' union
select * from table_1 where table_1.column3 ilike '%value%';
```

but use a single variable for '%value%', something like this:

```
do $$
    declare
        my_var TEXT;
    begin
        my_var = '%value%';
        select * from table_1 where table_1.column1 ilike my_var union
        select * from table_1 where table_1.column2 ilike my_var union
        select * from table_1 where table_1.column3 ilike my_var;
end $$;
```

but it doesn't seem to work (I'm kind of new to this) and I can't find the solution to do this. It doesn't have to be a do/end statement.  I'm just trying to declare a variable to use more than once in the query, so that I don't have to copy and paste '%value%' 3 times every time I want to change it (keep in mind this %value% will always be the same; hence why I want it to be in my_var).  Just want to change it once for all three statements and print out the same details.

Comment: What's your definition of " it doesn't seem to work" and don't forget this construction will never return anything: It's a DO block. "The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void"

Comment: What is the point? You are actually writing more code and (imho) less clear code for what you are after and getting less value from it,

Comment: I essentially just want to do the same 3 select queries to print out all the rows without repeat using the same variable for the ilike values.  I don't want to copy and paste '%someValue%' 3 different times.  Just want to change one value for all 3 select statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function
> with no parameters, returning **void**. It is parsed and executed a single
> time.

> The name of the procedural language the code is written in. If
> omitted, the default is plpgsql.

PL/pgsql reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Since **do command code block** is returning void, we can use raise notice to extract/debug what we do. To print out something from console, generally we need some variable to hold what we want to compute/final result.
The following is an simple example to count the return query rows.

```
CREATE temp TABLE a1 (
    column1 text,
    column2 text,
    column3 text
);

INSERT INTO a1
    VALUES ('value', 'test', 'test1');

INSERT INTO a1
    VALUES ('misc', 'value2', 'test2');

INSERT INTO a1
    VALUES ('misc1', 'test3', 'value3');

DO $$
DECLARE
    my_var text;
    _count bigint;
BEGIN
    my_var = '%value%';
    SELECT
        count(*) INTO _count
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM a1 WHERE column1 ILIKE my_var
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM a1 WHERE column2 ILIKE my_var
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM a1 WHERE column3 ILIKE my_var
        ) cte;
    RAISE NOTICE '_count = %', _count;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the rows instead of just the count?  Just like the "select * union" above it?  I essentially just want to do the same query but I don't want to copy and paste the '%value%" 3 different times when I can just hold one variable.

Comment: yes, you can see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d6f1e7629f0e2c1f42573ef04d94d881) @H.Kim

Comment: that demo showed me exactly what I needed, thank you!